# How to make Interactive program in BST ? C Lang

Tags: c, memory, struct, binary-search-tree, interactive

I need to to open and read multiple text files which will be stored similar to binary search tree construction.
NOTE: They all need to be opened and their content stored before user enters his input.

I really do need some advice, because I do not see my errors any more.

However, what I really don't get, is how to make it **interactive** ?
When I press 'A', it needs to read text from the left node and opposite.

Structure of output:

> ------------------\n
>   \n
>   Title\n
>   file1 // file present - 'A'
>   file2 // file empty/not empty - 'B'\n
>   Text\n
>   \n
>   Your choice (A/B):\n

This is how the programs output should look at the beginning:
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoKlb.png)

Elements of struct

```
typedef struct _Elements_
{
  char* title_;
  struct _Elements_* left;
  struct _Elements_* right;
  char* text_;
} Elements;
```

//Forward initialization is present

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char returned_value;
  Elements element;

  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: ./ass2 [file-name]\n");
    return 1;
  }

  returned_value = openFile(&element, argv[1]);

  while(returned_value != ('A' || 'B'))
  {
    repeatEntry(returned_value); // Function to scan the value
  }

  // Tricky part! Read from left ???
  if(returned_value == 'A')
  {
    printf("%s",element.left->text_);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%s",element.right->text_);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

//Here i wanna initialize node elements

// For every malloc, I have to make sure that it succeeded

```
Elements* newNode(Elements* element)
{
  Elements* newNode = (Elements*)malloc(sizeof(Elements));
  if(newNode == NULL)
  {
    printf("[ERR] Out of memory.\n");
     return (void*)2; // void* - to avoid warning of different type?
  }
  newNode->title_ = NULL;
  newNode->left = NULL;
  newNode->right = NULL;
  newNode->text_ = NULL;

  return newNode;
}
```

//Function that opens the files

```
char openFile(Elements* element, char* input)
{
  // Create new memory if tree is empty
  if(element == NULL)
  {
    return newNode(element);
  }
  FILE* file_open = fopen(input, "r");
  if (file_open == NULL)
  {
    printf("[ERR] Could not read file %s.\n", input);
    return 3;
  }

  // Local variables to handle the parsing file ?
  char line[80];
  int lenght_of_the_line; // Was just for me
  int line_number = 0; // this also

  // Do i really need local variables beside struct ? 
  char* title_local = NULL;
  char* first_file = NULL;
  char* second_file = NULL;
  char* text_local = NULL;

  while(fgets(line, 80, file_open))
  {
    lenght_of_the_line = strlen(line);
    //printf("%d ", lenght_of_the_line);
    //printf("%s ", line);

    // Get title
    if((line[lenght_of_the_line - 1] == '\n') && (line_number == 0))
    {

      title_local = (char*)malloc(lenght_of_the_line * (sizeof(char)) + 1);
      if(title_local == NULL)
      {
        printf("[ERR] Out of memory.\n");
        return 2;
      }
      strcpy(title_local, line);
      printf("%s ", element->title_ = title_local);
      printf("\n");
    }

    // Get 1st file name
    else if( (line[lenght_of_the_line - 1] == '\n') && (line_number == 1) )
    {
      if( (line[lenght_of_the_line - 5] == '.') &&
          (line[lenght_of_the_line - 4] == 't') &&
          (line[lenght_of_the_line - 3] == 'x') &&
          (line[lenght_of_the_line - 2] == 't') )
      {
        // Allocate enough memory for first file name
        first_file = (char*)malloc(lenght_of_the_line * (sizeof(char)) + 1);
        if(first_file == NULL)
        {
          printf("[ERR] Out of memory.\n");
          return 2;
        }
        strcpy(first_file, line);

         //name of file to open and store to left node
         //Seems to work, since I got no error
        openFile(element->left, first_file);
      }
    }

    // Get 2nd file name
    else if( (line[lenght_of_the_line - 1] == '\n') && (line_number == 2) )
    {
      if( (line[lenght_of_the_line - 5] == '.') &&
          (line[lenght_of_the_line - 4] == 't') &&
          (line[lenght_of_the_line - 3] == 'x') &&
          (line[lenght_of_the_line - 2] == 't') )
      {
        second_file = (char*)malloc(lenght_of_the_line * (sizeof(char)) + 1);
        if(second_file == NULL)
        {
          printf("[ERR] Out of memory.\n");
          return 2;
        }
        strcpy(second_file, line);
        openFile(element->right, second_file);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      text_local = (char*)malloc(lenght_of_the_line * (sizeof(char)) + 1);
      if(text_local == NULL)
        {
          printf("[ERR] Out of memory.\n");
          return 2;
        }
      strcpy(text_local, line);
      element->text_ = text_local;
      printf("%s", element->text_);
    }

    // Increase line number for 1
    line_number++;
  }
  //free(line);

  fclose(file_open);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Your choice (A/B)? ");
  char user_input;
  scanf("%c", &user_input);

  // DONT FORGET TO FREE THE MEMORY !

  return user_input;
}
```

Comment: What keeps you from creating a BST with pointers to "strings" with files content? You can add more structure with linked lists of string-pointers. For texts of unknown lenght use malloced memory.

Comment: You are asking "How exactly should I do that?" By reading up on the concepts, playing with tutorials on the matter and building up from small, individually tested parts. First one small file read into malloced memory and printed from there. Then introduce the BST to link to the first part of each file. Do not neglect the reading in of user input, many traps are waiting for you there.

Comment: I am pretty sure by the way, that this `while(returned_value != ('A' || 'B'))` does not do what you expect. It compares the returned value to whatever value your compiler uses to represent `true`. You probably mean `while((returned_value != 'A') && (returned_value !=  'B'))`.

Comment: @Yunnosch  it is one at the time, so `while((returned_value != 'A') || (returned_value != 'B'))` is actually what i need. Will try it.

Comment: `((returned_value != 'A') || (returned_value != 'B'))` will absolutely always be true. I recommend to use `&&`. Think how anything can be 'A' and at the same time be 'B', which is would be the only way out of your loop.

Comment: @Yunnosch Good point. I wasnt paying attention to the != sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
while(returned_value != ('A' || 'B'))
```

does not do what you probably expect. It compares the returned value to whatever value your compiler uses to represent `true`.
Currently your loop is hence likely to seem an endless loop, while waiting for returned_value to be identical to `true`.

You need

```
while((returned_value != 'A') && (returned_value != 'B'))
```

This will leave the loop when `returned_value` is identical to either 'A' or 'B'.
That way the endless loop problem is solved, which is likely the core problem preventing your file BST from being interactive.

By the way, for users convenience I recommend to also accept 'a' or 'b'.

For avoiding a "try again" after each input, use

```
scanf(" %c", &user_input);
```

with a space at the start, for ignoring leading white space, including the newline/return after each entered 'A' or 'B'.

Comment: We were instructed just to accept capital A or B. By the way, why is the output multiplying for the number of inserted elements ?
`Your choice (A/B):` as //insert two elements -enter
It shows:
`Your choice (A/B): Your choice (A/B):`

Comment: It probably reacts to the newline/return after the A or B. You need to ignore it.

Comment: Try `scanf(" %c", &user_input);`, note the space at the start, which will ignore all leading whitespace.

Comment: Good luck with the rest of the project. I like the idea of making an easily editable mini-text adventure.